# What are the lyrics of the opening of this youtube video ("La Victoire de L'Amour"', 2022 version)?

Tags: transcription

I must have listened to the opening to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk3JJsF71oo) daily youtube series about 30 times now, but I still can't make it out very well.

---

The following is my pseudo-transcription. In various parts where I cannot guess any reasonable word, I write down bolded nonsense words that stand for what sounds I hear:

> ***En ce*** juste ***-euh*** dans Toi, vivra mon secours. 
>  Viens ce **mé** dans mon
> âme, le grand de l'amour. 
>  Je traverse un désign<sup>1</sup>, et je meurt de
> soif. 
>  Montre-moi le mystère qui garde de la foi.

(I'm guessing that "juste-euh" is really just "juste" with the final usually-silent "e" being pronounced, as sometimes happens in music  (I think?).)

But even apart from the bolded words, my guess at the lyrics has a lot that seem questionable to me:

- "vivra mon secours": "will live my help". How is something inanimate like "help" able to "live", and why is it in a future tense, instead of a present tense? Wouldn't it make sense for the singer to be saying "My help lives only in You" instead of "My help **will** live only in You"?
- what is "le grand de l'amour"? If I put this into DeepL, the closest translation it gives that makes sense is "The great one of love". Is this true; ie "The great one" means God? Is using the adjective "grand" as "le grand" to mean "the great person" a common thing to do?
- what does "meurt de soif" mean? "mourir" in WordReference doesn't have the meaning of "to quench [thirst]". So the literal meaning I read ("to kill thirst") doesn't seem to make sense to me.

So, there are sounds that I can't find reasonable words to match in this opening, and also sentences that I can indeed find words to match, but I have doubts if these words are correct. That's why I'm curious to see what the actual lyrics are.

---

<sup>1. Because I seem to listen to young speakers from Montréal the most, I'm most familiar hearing "en" (in "dans", "-ment", "ans", etc) being pronounced as a much more closed vowel (high-tongue) than would be pronounced in the accent of Standard French, closer to Standard French's pronunciation of "in" ("vin", "mains", "bain"). Most hosts and many guests (though not all) in this show from Québec seem to pronounce "en" in the more-closed-vowel way that I'm familiar with; and these speakers also tend to pronounce "in" using a characteristically Canadian French dipthong (sort of like "è" sliding to a nasalized "i" ("i" as in "vie"")?).</sup>

<sup>So it surprises me that "grand" is pronounced with the closed pronunciation that I'm familair with.. but "viens" is not pronounced with a dipthong (and "désign", if that's the actual word, is also not pronounced with a dipthong). This makes the "en" in "grand" and the "in" in "viens" rather similar! I am indeed able to hear the difference, but it surprises me that any speaker -- such as the singer, here -- would pronounce these two vowels so closely. It surprises me so much, that I question if my transcritpion of "viens", "grand", "désign" etc are even correct.</sup>

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to understand but this is what I get after many hearings:

> *Un seul geste de toi guidera mon secours* (or *viendra mon secours* thanks @anonymous2)
> *Viens semer dans mon âme le grain de l'amour
>
> Je traverse un désert et je meurs de soif
>
> Montre-moi le mystère qui garde la foi*

Comment: wow. my attempt was way, *way* off...!

Comment: can you articulate what made it difficult for you to understand? this might help me identify difficulties i, myself, might have when understanding lyrics in French, myself.

Comment: You understood *et je meurs de soif* while I didn't without your help.

Comment: The ways some *R*'s are pronounced made understanding some words like *guidera* and *traverse* difficult to me. It might be a Québec pronunciation or a foreign one.

Comment: Agreed with this. I had to slow it down and relisten a few times as well to get "me-eurs".

Comment: I'm wondering whether "guidera" might not be "viendra"

Comment: @anonymous2 That's what I first tought but I do not hear the double *A* that is needed for this part to be *viendra **à** mon secours*.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh, I was thinking of "mon secours" being the subject of "viendra," after the style of Psalm 121 "d'où me viendra le secours"

Comment: @anonymous2 That's indeed an eventuality I missed. Answer updated.

Comment: was their a judge present?